# Difference between Dispatcher.RunAsync and ThreadPool.RunAsync in UWP

Tags: asynchronous, canvas, uwp, dispatcher

I implemented a basic AutoSave method which is executed every time a user draws a stroke on an InkCanvas in UWP.

I followed the code snippet here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/submit-a-work-item-to-the-thread-pool and also another approach using Dispatcher.RunAsync . I came up with 3 methods, one of which throws a Marshall exception

**Method 1 (throws) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/submit-a-work-item-to-the-thread-pool)**

```
    private void AutoSave()
    {
        IAsyncAction asyncAction
            = ThreadPool.RunAsync(
                async (workItem) =>
                {  
                  await ExportInk.SaveInkToLocalFileAsync(inkCanvas);
                });
        autoSaveWorkItem = asyncAction;

    }
```

**Method 2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/submit-a-work-item-to-the-thread-pool)**

```
    private void AutoSave()
    {
        IAsyncAction asyncAction
            = ThreadPool.RunAsync(
                async (workItem) =>
                {
                    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new DispatchedHandler(async () =>
                        {
                            await ExportInk.SaveInkToLocalFileAsync(inkCanvas);
                        }));
                });
        autoSaveWorkItem = asyncAction;
    }
```

**Method 3 (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d425e995-6822-4059-898f-0b5ff9586dfe/uwpcthe-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread-?forum=wpdevelop)**

```
    private async void AutoSave()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
          await ExportInk.SaveInkToLocalFileAsync(inkCanvas);
        });
    }
```

**Question 1** Is method 1 throwing because I am manipulating a UI element (InkCanvas)?

**Question 2** What is the difference between Method 2 and 3 and why method 3 seems to be the method to go for?

Thanks in advance for any recommendation

Comment: Q1: You are accessing (probably not manipulating) a UI element in a non-UI thread, which typically results in an exception. Just catch and check the exception. Q2: The Dispatcher instance should be the same on both cases, hence method 3 is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Yes. Each Window in your application has a single main thread for it's UI, and it's only on this thread that you can manipulate UI elements. This can be accessed via the Dispatcher for that Window, which dispatches messages from any thread too that Window's UI thread.

ThreadPool.RunAsync creates a workitem to run on some arbitrary ThreadPool thread, which is probably not usually ever going to be your UI thread.

Because you're accessing a UI object for some of it's UI properties you need to be on the UI thread to do this.

2 - For method 2 your're pointlessly popping off to a threadpool thread just to tell it to go back to the UI thread to do it's work. It's unnecessary as none of the work is going to get done on that thread because the Dispatcher is sending it all off the UI thread anyway. 3 avoid thats - although if autosave is already called from the UI thread there's not even a need for a Dispatcher call.

You're actually using the same Dispatcher on 2 & 3 if you're in a single window application, just different ways of accessing it. The way you're accessing via 2 is the way you would do it if you're code was not in the code-behind of a DependencyObject.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject#remarks for notes about Dispatcher

Comment: Thx for @JohnnyWestlake but not all applicants have the single thread and some application can use multi UI thread. And when you use Dispather.Async that you use the UI element's thread and it can not be main thread.

Comment: @lindexi in UWP, a UI thread is attached usually to a Window, so to get multiple UI threads you need multiple Windows, and you need to use the correct Dispatcher for each UI element to access them. You can't give a single window two UI threads. Still stands that only the main dispatcher for a window can give you access to that Windows UI Elements, using another dispatcher won't let you.